QGIS labels switching upside down when using Curved placement
In QGIS I've always had the issue where certain labels will switch upside down when moving it along a line, when the placement is set to Curved, in all versions. Is this a bug or is there a way around this? I've tried reversing the line direction which worked once.

Have you tried this upside-down setting in the "rendering" tab  https://i.sstatic.net/9rgHabKN.png?

Yes, I always have that option turned on but it doesn't seem to make a difference when moving these labels. By default the labels are placed right side up. It's only when I start moving some along the line, with the Curved setting.
